# Windows Workflow Foundation for .net Core

Tags: .net-core, workflow, workflow-foundation, .net-5

How to use MS workflow foundation in .net Core 5.0.

Is there a MS standard implementation for Workflows in .net core 5?

Answer (score 5):

A company called UiPath has forked Windows Workflow Foundation to be compatible with .NET 5. https://github.com/UiPath/corewf

Answer (score 3):

WWF is not ported to .NET Core/.NET 5.
It is mentioned on [What's new page of .NET 5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/dotnet-five#net-50-doesnt-replace-net-framework). You can check alternatives (mentioned on the page), but I never used them, so I can't tell more.